# IndentationError- py

Tags: python

I'm new in programming, in Python language I've got an error and I don`t understand why, the code is bellow:

[image]

Comment: the `while` identation is incorrect. one space to the right please

Comment: better to use `tabs` in python then `space` or in your ide set 1 tab to 4 space

Comment: You need to fix the indentations on lines 8-13 (inclusive). Add 1 space for each line (except empty lines)

Comment: Worked with one space to the right of while and moved the great_magicians list into while. Thank you guys!

Comment: Actually, strictly speaking, the problem if that the `for` loop (line 15) is one space to the right of the `while` on line 10. However, to preserve the conventional 4-space indent, you should make the fix in lines 10 to 13, as @Adam suggested. As for spaces versus tabs spaces are the preferred method, as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#:~:text=Spaces%20are%20the%20preferred%20indentation,converted%20to%20using%20spaces%20exclusively.). Spaces are also portable between different editors, while tabs have more potential for problems when sharing code.

Answer (score -2):

Add one space on lines `8` and `10-13`.
I hope this helps.

Comment: If you meant line 15, then that is a quick and dirty fix.

Comment: No, there is one extra space on line 16.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  That line can have whatever indentation it likes. Its line 15 which disagrees with line 10